# Fragments' lifecycles preventing me from using notifyDataSetChanged upon activity swaps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, arraylist, android-activity

I have a generic android tabbed setup with the default code.

I also have a second activity, `listaddactivity` that basically just constructs a custom `parcelable` object and spits it back out to the `mainactivity` with all the tabs and fragments.

My second tab contains a `ListFragment`; which I attempt to update with the data I received from `listaddactivity`'s intent sent to `mainactivity`. My problem lies in that I have discovered that my `ListFragment` is being destroyed and reconstructed upon switching activities; as well as the data that is contained in it. Meaning that whenever I received my intent in my `mainactivity` that came from my `listaddactivity` it will update the list; but only with the latest object that I've constructed (not storing all previous objects).

How can I preserve this `ArrayList<myCustomObject>` of objects or preserve the `ListFragment` as to allow for the list to continually grow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

I managed to make a work around for this by using a singleton as outlined by this page:

https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992

This allowed me to store and retrieve the arraylist from the singleton; and use it on any fragment I pleased by instantiating the singleton.